# What happened to a question I (might have) posted about the word 'feminazis'?

Tags: support, questions, offensive

I posted a question (at least, I *think* I posted one) about the usage of the term 'feminazi'. Where is the question? Is it deleted? What was wrong with it? If it was inappropriate, can I get a private message explaining it?

I asked about a term that would describe feminists who don't respect others' individual freedom...for me, the word 'radical feminist' is likely to be misconstrued. I asked if 'feminazi' would be an understandable alternative, and, if not, what a better one might be.
<sub>[Note: This last paragraph was added in an edit based [off of this comment](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3115/i-think-i-asked-a-question-about-usage-of-feminazis#comment7444_3116)]</sub>

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81507/is-nazi-an-actual-english-word

Comment: I'm not sure whether my edit is actually useful, but I tried to add more context. Unfortunately, it kind of invalidates the current answer, which was based off of a misunderstanding. Someone else might want to re-edit it.

Answer (score 1):

[Is the term X-nazi offensive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81703/is-the-term-x-nazi-offensive?noredirect=true) was closed as a duplicate of [Is "grammar nazi" politically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21935/is-grammar-nazi-politically-correct). The question wasn't deleted, but under certain circumstances, you might be silently redirected to the question that remains open. I've added a parameter to the link in this question to stop the silent redirect so that you can see your original question.

I should also note that a link to the question should appear on the questions tab of your profile.

Comment: Not that question. I asked another one. Basically I asked what would be a term for feminists that doesn't respects others' individual freedom. Libertarian feminists respects others' freedom. Radical feminists do not. However, radical doesn't convey the idea well. Having women votes, may be radical. I wonder if feminazi is indeed the term.

Comment: @JimThio Mods can see all questions asked by a user, including deleted ones, and I don't see anything more recent showing up on your profile. There were some database issues yesterday that affected question asking, however, and your question may have been lost, if that was when it was asked.

Comment: I can ask again. But I fear the question is so politically incorrect, downvoted, and closed and I don't want to repeat it. I am really only interested in the meaning.

Comment: @JimThio: If you're really only interested in the meaning, then why ask on EL&U?  Why not just [look it up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminazi)? (If you were only inquiring about basic meaning, there's a good chance I'd downvote and/or vote to close, but not because it's politically incorrect; rather, because it's general reference.) I recommend reading through the Wikipedia entry as a start; there are also several links on that page.  Then, do some more research using Google. If you still have a question after all that, you might ask, but present your findings in your question.

Comment: The reference doesn't say anything at all if it's offensive or not and the meaning I have in mind is different than that. I'll ask again but I'll be careful.